# In what way do I change the color of Jcombobox Java cell on mouse hover?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change the color when I mouse over a cell on a combo box. Do I use a mouse event for that or just this cell renderer?

In what way do I change the color of `JComboBox` cell on mouse hover?

Here's my code:

```
jComboBox2.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (isSelected){
            c.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));
        }
        if(index == 0){
            c.setForeground(new Color(242,242,242));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        if(index == 1){
            c.setForeground(new Color(101,150,226));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        if(index == 2){
            c.setForeground(new Color(77,105,205));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        if(index == 3){
            c.setForeground(new Color(137,71,255));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        if(index == 4){
            c.setForeground(new Color(212,43,230));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        if(index == 5){
            c.setForeground(new Color(235,75,75));
            c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
        }
        else {

        }
        return c;
    }
});
```

[image: ComboBoxImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

I just have to nest if to change the color on hover

Like this

```
if(index == 0){
    c.setForeground(new Color(242,242,242));
    c.setBackground(new Color(26,35,48));
    if (isSelected) {
        c.setBackground(new Color(49,62,80));
    }
}
```

[ComboBoxImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMiBP.png)

Comment: now the question is, after I click a certain cell, it should also change the foreground color of the combobox. jComboBox2.setForeground(new Color(211,211,211)); inside if(isSelected){} wont work.

Comment: *now the question is* - one question per posting. If you have another question then create a new question and post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Question:  **it should also change the foreground color of the combobox. jComboBox2.setForeground(new Color(211,211,211)); inside if(isSelected){} wont work**

Place the if(isSelected){c.setForeground(new Color(211,211,211));} at end of **else** statement so the we can override color..

Comment: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)